# OpalCryptoErase.exe for linux

Tags: hard-disk, encryption

I have a tool name OpalCryptoErase.exe which lets me reset the encryption keys on my opal ssd disk.
Of course I lose my data along the way but I don’t care I just want to reset the disk to the initial "factory" state or to use it again without the encryption.
I familiar a little bit with msed tool that also let you configure the encryption but in order to  reset the disk I need an initial password , cert file or PSID.

Tha nice thing about OpalCryptoErase.exe is that it does not require anything in order to reset it.

So my question is there a tool that can do the same in Linux because the OpalCryptoErase.exe is for windows and I need something for Linux.

Comment: In some cases, the PSID might actually be printed on the label on top of the disk. [At least it was for this Lenovo user.](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-Tablets/OPAL-Drive-Erase-Utility/m-p/4103890#M34423)